# How can i copy from excel and paste into Vba

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Please I am working on a program that computes matrix but rather than manually entering the matrix I am trying to copy the matrix from an excel sheet and paste on my Visual basic running interface. Is there anyway I can go about this?

**NOTE:** Please i am not trying the load the matrix from the excel sheet into visual basic. I am trying to copy from the sheet to a visual basic Running interface.